# algebra simplifying containing logs question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given: $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2n-1}(\frac{3}{2})^in = n\frac{1 - (\frac{3}{2})^{\log_2n}}{1 - \frac{3}{2}} = 2n\frac{3^{\log_2n} - 2^{\log_2n}}{2^{\log_2n}} = 2n\frac{3^{\log_2n} - 2^{\log_2n}}{n} =2(3^{\log_2n} - 2^{\log_2n}) =2(n^{\log_3} - n)$

My question is how did $n\frac{1 - (\frac{3}{2})^{\log_2n}}{1 - \frac{3}{2}}$ become $2n\frac{3^{\log_2n} - 2^{\log_2n}}{2^{\log_2n}}$? Specifically, how the denominator $1 - \frac{3}{2}$ was changed to $2^{\log_2n}$?

Comment: From the limits of the sum I'm inferring that $n$ is a power of $2$.  If that's the case, replace $n$ with $2^k$ and $\log_2 n$ with $k$.  I think it will be easier to simplify that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the intermediate steps:

\begin{eqnarray*}n\frac{1 - (\frac{3}{2})^{\log_2n}}{1 - \frac{3}{2}}
& = & n\frac{\frac{2^{\log_2n} - 3^{\log_2n}}{2^{\log_2n}}}{\frac{2-3}{2}} \\
& = & 2n\frac{2^{\log_2n} - 3^{\log_2n}}{-2^{\log_2n}} \\
& = & 2n\frac{3^{\log_2n} - 2^{\log_2n}}{2^{\log_2n}} \\
& = & \ldots
\end{eqnarray*}